# Should I put down underlayment when putting a layer of tile on top of another?

Tags: underlayment

I have two layers of tile down. The suggestion is to tear off the first layer of tile and then put on new Armstrong tile. One contractor has underlayment in the bid, while the other does not.

Do we need the underlayment?

Comment: What line and type of vinyl tile?

Comment: If 'imperfections in the sub floor' is a quote from the contractor, then yes. https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=a61zcQ1hcgo

Comment: You're going to make some future archeologist very happy by burying the previous "historic" floor.  Or some future homeowner less happy if they need to open up the floor for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Armstrong subfloors and underlayment manual](http://www.armstrong.com/content2/flooring/files/80986.pdf), all Armstrong vinyl tile installations require an underlayment.

If you don't have an approved underlayment, you may not receive full warranty coverage for the tiles.

Further, the underlayment is secured using mechanical fasteners through the old tiles to the subfloor, so you don't have to worry about whether the adhesive will secure the new tiles to the old tiles. The adhesive will bond correctly with an appropriately chosen underlayment, and the tiles will not bubble or spread due to temperature fluctuations and differing rates of expansion between the new tile and the old.  This can only be guaranteed when the adhesive works, and most tile surfaces are designed to be difficult to stick to or stain, so finding a suitable adhesive might be difficult.